# How to update query after submitting the form using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a form that its working,I output the records in the test.cfm file and after I submit the form the values are inserted into the table.

The issue is, How do I update the table in test.cfm after I submit the form and insert the new record?

test.cfm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ProcessValidateForm() {
        $("##ProcessStatus").html('Processing...');
        $.post('insert_view.cfc?method=UpdateMethod&returnFormat=plain',
            $("##ValidateForm").serialize(),
            function(data, ProcessStatus) {
                data = $.trim(data)
                if (data == 'success') {
                    $("##ProcessStatus").html('Record Insert Successfully');

                }
                $('input[type="text"],textarea').val('');
            });
        return false
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("##ValidateForm").validate({
            rules: {
                FirstName: {
                    required: true
                },
                EmailID: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }

            },
            messages: {
                FirstName: '&nbsp;**',
                EmailID: '&nbsp;**'

            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit(ProcessValidateForm);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<cfquery datasource="test" name="getimeline">
    SELECT * FROM testing_table
</cfquery>


<table id="tablesorter-demo"  >
    output query getimeline here
</table>
```

insert_view.cfc file

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset ODBCDataSource="test">
    <cffunction name="UpdateMethod" access="remote" output="false" returnType="string">
        <cfquery name="InserRecord" datasource="#ODBCDataSource#">
            insert into testing_table ....
        </cfquery>
        <cfreturn "success">
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: The easy way is to forget javascript altogether and simply submit the form.

Comment: @danbracuk you mean without any ajax/javascript , just have form and insert into ?

Comment: I mean have the form post data to a ColdFusion page that does what it needs to do with that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of coldfusion but looks like the issue is with the caching of the request. Please try to disable cache somehow. Usually, you can disable caching globally using $.ajaxSetup(), for example:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Please let me now if that worked for you.